# Visual studio 2012 cursor navigating to errors while typing.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I'm using visual studio 2012. Whenever I start typing it re-navigates my cursor and thus whatever I type to any errors that are present. If there are more than one error present it starts switching between all the errors over and over again as if i was Alt + Tabbing really fast. If no errors are present then my typing is not navigated away from where I'm working. I've unplugged my keyboard just to make sure it wasn't some embedded functionality with the Microsoft Sculpture (highly unlikely). I've gone through the list of options and can't find anything relating to this as well as read tons of pages on VS errors.

Comment: Typing induced warning/error or Compilation error that it navigates you to?

Comment: Worst case you can always reset your settings.

Comment: After several reboots to both visual studio and my computer it finally went away. The only thing i can think of is after switching branches and clicking 'Reload all' that something got crossed wired. I'd still like an answer on this as it's not the first time I've seen it.

Comment: The issue came up again. I've reset my settings and that hasn't fixed it. If I add new errors to the file I'm working in it will also move my cursor to any and all new errors.